# Are there no gophers in Spain?

Tags: traducción, españa, hispanoamérica, animales

In *The Grapes of Wrath*/*Las Uvas de la Ira* the English text mentions a gopher hole; the Spanish translation says, "la madriguera de una ardilla."

But isn't an ardilla a squirrel? Why no specific word for gopher? Are gophers unknown in Spain (I'm assuming the translator was from Spain, but if not: are there no gophers in Latin America?

translate.com gives *gopher* as *ardilla de la tierra*. So a gopher is a *squirrel of the earth*? Actually, there already is a ground (as opposed to tree) squirrel. And a gopher ain't it.

So what's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animal called in english as "gopher" is called in spanish

> **tuzas**, **taltuzas** o **ratas de abazones**.

You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher) and read this:

> Gophers are endemic to North and Central America.

So no, there are no gophers in Spain, nor in most of latin America. This is why the translator chose a better known animal, the well known squirrel we all (besides Donald) love.

Comment: Probably a better translation would been "topo" or "topillo"?

Comment: @Bardo Probably :)

Comment: doesn't "topo" mean "mole"?

Comment: @WalterMitty Yes, "topo" means "mole" but "topillo" is quite a different animal, actually like a hamster.

Comment: Better yet, go to the Wikipedia article on "Gopher" (by clicking on the link above), and then select "Español" from the language menu on the left.  You'll get the corresponding Wikipedia article in Spanish.  Lots of detail.

Comment: @WalterMitty Doing that provides no extra info about how to translate. "Tuzas" will continue being an almost unknown word for the reader. "Ardillas" instead is a well known word.

Comment: if a gopher is an almost unknown animal for the reader, it stands to reason that the noun for a gopher will be an almost unknown word.